# wordpress - Big post IDs, is it Okay in the future?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

A client of mine has requested that a list of posts would be fetched through a data feed and a cron job will run each 6 hours to delete all the previously fetched data and add new data as posts.

The data is about **250 posts, fetched each 6 hours**. My concern is about the posts IDs of this blog will get very very big in about 6 months from now.. for no reason!

Should I do something about it? Like for example trying to edit the posts instead of deleting and adding (while this might be a stupid workaround, it will slow down post IDs increment for no reason)

Thoughts please, Thanks!

Comment: 182,500 posts? Pah, that's nothing. Come back to us in 10 years.

Comment: /me looks at ID in the url of this questions. Although (imho) it would look nicer if you could edit instead. But don't worry too much if that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress uses a `bigint` field type for a post `ID`. [bigint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) has a maximum value of 9223372036854775807.

Pretty sure you'll be fine...

Comment: That's very convincing :)

Comment: Assuming you deal with 1000 posts per day, you'll be fine for 9,223,372,036,854,775 days. Making a bit of an assumption...but the concept holds true. There's really nothing wrong with large IDs in your case.